# set mysql session and global sql_mode when service start

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql Server version: 5.5.37 and in current mysql whenever i will restart mysql service that time i saw below results

```
mysql> select @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
+--------------------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.sql_mode                          |
+--------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @@session.sql_mode;
+--------------------------------------------+
| @@session.sql_mode                         |
+--------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But i want to set mysql mode for both(session as well as global) whenever service is restart.i  have also tried to put below line in  /etc/my.cnf file
but its not working fine

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

so is it possible to set from any core file or else where ?
please shine on this topic
i need help to set up session and global both sql_mode  to 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'

Answer (score 0):

This is how I set SQL mode in my `/etc/my.conf` file:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Make sure your MySQL daemon has permissions to read this file. Also, check if there are any other `my.conf` files that may override your value. MySQL searches and reads config files in multiple locations. Read more here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html